# Spring Security : How to access a protected service from the init method of a context bean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**My setup** :

In a Spring MVC 3.1 application, I have a Spring Security protected service :

```
@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()") // ("hasRole('USER')") doesn't work either
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService, PasswordEncoder
```

I'm trying to use this service from the init() method of a bean declared in my context :

```
<bean class="com.xxx.scripts.FillDbWithInitialValues" init-method="contextInit" />
```

The class :

```
public class FillDbWithInitialValues
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    public void contextInit()
    {
        User test = userService.getUser(1);
    }
}
```

Extract of my security.xml file :

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />   

<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    (...)
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="userService" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

**The problem** :

When I start the application, I get an exception :

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Why is this happening? 
How can my bean be "authenticated" so it can use the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no user authenticated there's no way of checking his roles. If you want that bean to be authenticated before calling the method i think you could try something in this way:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new user here);  
User test = userService.getUser(1);
```

Comment: I didn't think I would have to do this for my "internal" actions, but this works, indeed! I created a "system" user, with a ROLE_SYSTEM role, and I use that user for my system actions. Thanks.